# Error about unmatched parenthesis running simple imputer

Tags: pandas, numpy, transformation

```
dput(head("CustomTransformerData.csv"))
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Applies the SimpleImputer class to the data, where the strategy is set to mean. The name of this step should be "imputer".

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

fileName = "CustomTransformerData.csv"
custom_transform = pd.read_csv("CustomTransformerData.csv")

data_num = custom_transform.drop(['x3'], axis = 1); #created the df for categorical data

data_cat = custom_transform.drop(['x1', 'x2', 'x4', 'x5'], axis = 1); #created the df for numerical data

#importing sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin

##creating the transformer
class Assignment4Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, drop_x4 = True, y = None):
        self.drop_x4 = drop_x4 #flag to drop the x4 column
    
    def fit_transform(self, data, y=None):
        return self

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline #importing the pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer #importing the SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler #importint the preprocessor

def transform(self, data): #starting the function to determine x4
        #not adding the x3 categorical data
        
       
    if self.drop_x4: #a flag to catch and drop x4, giving a new index
        data = np.delete(data, 2, axis=1)
        return np.c_[data, new_col]

num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')]) # this is where I encounter the below error

  File "/var/folders/5v/f6glw1515sqbvblc482qs47c0000gn/T/ipykernel_42484/2823414947.py", line 1
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')])
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '('
```

Alternatively, I tried this as well, which did not error, but then the next code errored:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')), 
                         ('attribs_adder', Assignment4Transformer()),])

std_scaler= StandardScaler(num_pipeline)
 
# Splitting the independent and dependent variables
std_scaler = data_num.data
response = data_num.target
 
# standardization 
scale = object.fit_transform(data_num)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/5v/f6glw1515sqbvblc482qs47c0000gn/T/ipykernel_42484/1423714864.py in <module>
----> 1 std_scaler= StandardScaler(num_pipeline)
      2 
      3 # Splitting the independent and dependent variables
      4 std_scaler = data_num.data
      5 response = data_num.target

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

So I'm not sure if going the second route was truly correct, and I just need help with this portion:
Applies the custom Assignment4Transformer class to the data. Make sure that your custom transformer uses the default argument where you drop the  4
x
4
column. The name of this step should be "custom_trans".

Applies the StandardScaler class to the data. The name of this step should be "std_scaler?

Data: (since it doesn't appear to be carrying through

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5          
1   1.5 2.354152979 COLD    593 0.75            
2   2.5 3.31404772  WARM    340 2.083333333         
3   3.5 4.021604459 COLD    551 4.083333333         
4   4.5     COLD    2368    6.75            
5   5.5 5.847601001 WARM    2636    10.08333333         
6   6.5 7.229910044 WARM    2779    14.08333333         
7   7.5 7.997255234 HOT 1057    18.75           
8   8.5 9.203946542 COLD    819 24.08333333         
9   9.5 10.33534766 WARM    3349                
10  10.5    11.11214192 HOT 3235    36.75           
11  11.5    11.75961084 WARM    216 44.08333333         
12  12.5    12.62909577 WARM    2529    52.08333333         
13  13.5    14.08258887 COLD    1735    60.75           
14  14.5    14.65767801 HOT 1254    70.08333333         
15  15.5        HOT 1245    80.08333333         
16  16.6    17.18411403 WARM    310 90.75           
17  17.5    17.80077555 HOT 201 102.0833333         
18  18.5    18.57886101 HOT 1767    114.0833333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In your first code block...

This

```py
 num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')])
```

Should be this

```py
 num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'))])
```

I added a closing parenthesis after `SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')`

## In your second code block...

[`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#) is a class and needs to be instantiated before it can be used.

In your code here:

```py
num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')), 
                         ('attribs_adder', Assignment4Transformer()),])

std_scaler= StandardScaler(num_pipeline)
```

You give your `num_pipeline` to the class, but should instead define the `std_scaler`, and then use `.fit` or `.fit_transform` on data, or add it to the pipeline like so

```py
num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')), 
                         ('attribs_adder', Assignment4Transformer()),])

std_scaler= StandardScaler()

# applying to data
std_scaler.fit_transform(some_data)

# adding to pipeline at 0th step
num_pipeline.steps.insert(0, ("scale", std_scaler))

# last step
num_pipeline.steps.extend([("scale", std_scaler)])

# some other step???
num_pipeline.steps.insert(1, ("scale", std_scaler))
```